# How can I change my Windows 10 login back to Office 365 work login?

Tags: windows-10, login, office365

Office 365 login to windows 10 on work computer changed to my personal msn login and I can't change it back.  I can only login on a local account or microsoft account but not my work Office 365 account??  I don't want to login with a local account because it keeps making me verify for One Drive for business repetitively when saving documents.

Comment: An Office 365 is suppose to be a Microsoft Account...

Answer (score 0):

Just type in your work address.  If that address is both a work and personal logon you will have to select which one to use.  If you have not done this before know that:

1. Azure AD / O365 have to be set to allow you to connect your workstation
2. When using O365 account on windows 10 Cortana is disabled (and you can't enable it - it's slated for 'future' fix is not on the Azure or O365 road maps).